# Primefaces p:ajax + p:selectOneButton not calling bean setter

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Dears, at this code we have two ajax calls to set the payment method and the parcels number. The first call sets the bean perfectly. But the second not. It call the converter without any problem but the setter never is called. So the variable cartView.paymentParcel is always null.

```
<p:panel id="payMethodPanel" class="Container" header="2.#{msg.payment_method}">
    <p:selectOneRadio id="paymentRadio" layout="custom" value="#{cartView.paymentMethod}" converter="paymentConverter">
        <p:ajax process="paymentRadio" update="cartForm:payMethodPanel cartForm:summaryPanel" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{paymentView.paymentsMethods}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    <ui:repeat value="#{paymentView.paymentsMethods}" var="paym"> 
        <div class="MarTop10">
            <p:radioButton for="cartForm:paymentRadio" itemIndex="#{paymentView.index}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{msg[paym.name]} " />
            <h:outputFormat value="#{msg.discount_text}" rendered="#{fn:length(paym.parcels) eq 1 and paym.parcels[0].discount gt 0}">
                <f:param value="#{paym.parcels[0].discount}" />
            </h:outputFormat>
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.installment}" rendered="#{fn:length(paym.parcels) gt 1}"/>
            <p:selectOneButton id="parcelButtom" value="#{cartView.paymentParcel}" converter="paymentParcelConverter" rendered="#{fn:length(paym.parcels) gt 1 and cartView.paymentMethod eq paym}">
                <p:ajax process="parcelButtom" update="parcelButtom cartForm:summaryPanel" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{paym.parcels}" var="par" itemValue="#{par}" itemLabel="#{par.parcel}x #{par.interest eq 0 ? msg.without_interest : msg.with_interest}" />
            </p:selectOneButton>
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
    <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
</p:panel>
```

Bean Code

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "cartView")
public class CartView implements Serializable {
    private PaymentParcel paymentParcel;

    public PaymentParcel getPaymentParcel() {
        return paymentParcel;
    }

    public void setPaymentParcel(PaymentParcel paymentParcel) {
        this.paymentParcel = paymentParcel;
    }
}
```

=== Update ===

After analysing the ajax request I noticed an validation issue, and I put a p:message component to see whats happing and I get the following message:

```
cartForm:j_idt110:3:parcelButtom: Erro de validação: o valor não é válido
cartForm:j_idt110:3:parcelButtom: Validation error : invalid value
```

I don't understand why the value is invalid I debuged the converter: Here the code:

```
@FacesConverter("paymentParcelConverter")
public class PaymentParcelConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        String[] split = value.split(";");
        return new PaymentParcel(Long.parseLong(split[0]), Double.parseDouble(split[1]), Double.parseDouble(split[2]));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof PaymentParcel) {
            PaymentParcel parcel = (PaymentParcel) value;
            return new StringBuilder()
                .append(parcel.getParcel()).append(';')
                .append(parcel.getDiscount()).append(';')
                .append(parcel.getInterest()).toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Glassfish 4.1

Primefaces 5.3.0 + Modena Theme 2.1.1

Mojarra 2.2.13

Comment: Please share your java code as well.

Comment: Hi DiSol the java code is quite simple. I suspect that was a validation issue. Im investigating the ajax requests right now.

Comment: Do you have an equal method on your PaymentParcel class?

Comment: No I don't but I can't notice the impact on this context. I can't test now Im at bed with cell phone.

Comment: See my answer below, it explains the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new object in the converter each time but this object is not part of the list of the selecte items so an equal should be implemented in it. A more elegant solution would be to scan the list of select items in the converter and return the correct one instead of creating new object each and every time.